# Player camera targeting/locking another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game that uses a third person camera view, character centralized, no issues with that. But I can't find a way to "lock" on another object while keeping my character in view (Rocket League ball cam: https://youtu.be/FDcO04gXihM ).

I am aware of lookAt() method but it's not enough on its own. I still need to calculate the position of the camera to avoid staying between the player and the target. The problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ1PE.jpg

This is what I'm currently doing to move the camera (the "free cam"):

```
 if (freeCam) {
     transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, camTarget.transform.position, speed);
     transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, camTarget.transform.rotation, speed);
 } else {
     // Lock cam
 }
```

The camTarget is a game object parented to the player.

Comment: Sr but may I misunderstand you, but with a fixed camera you would just need to change the lookat of the camera object to look at the ball as example as it is in rocket league. The camera stays the same, as a child object of the player, so it moves with the player, and via the lookat you fix the view of the camera. nothing else. If I don't see your problem please tell a bit more then may I can assist you.

Comment: The problem is that when the player is facing the other side, the camera gets in between the player and the goal (since the camera is always behind the player). http://imgur.com/a/MdO9m I think some sort of calculation is needed to get the correct position of the camera but my math skills sucks.

Comment: I've edited your title to remove the "(Unity3D)" tag. Please take a look at [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/284827) where the general consensus is 'no'.

Comment: Use LookAt() to aim it at the target. Then using the Character's position and the target's position you're looking at, get a  degree of rotation and project a point X distance the opposite of that rotation from the character. This should ensure that the character is always between the camera and target object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now understand what your problem is and try to explain the solution.

Let's say you have the player object as PO and the target object TO and the camera object CO.

So when you want to achieve, to follow with the camera view always the target object and keep the player object in between, all you have to do ->

1. The CO needs to travel around the PO in an orbit (orbital camera) with a fixed distance.
2. Next create a vector from the point TO to PO (the center of the orbit of CO)
3. Then calculate the 2 hit points of the vector (TO|PO) with the orbit. You now have an enter hit point ENP and an exit hit point EXP.
4. As of vectors have always a direction the EXP will always be the further point if you keep the direction from TO to PO.
5. Set the CO position to EXP and lookat at TO
6. Apply an fixed offset to EXP corresponding to the world.upvector to always sit above the PO.
7. [optional] If surface exists, do a collision detection with EXP against the surface. If hit, set EXP to collision detection point, and set PO render to false. As soon  EXP is no longer colliding with surface set PO render to true.
8. [optional] If want to achieve to always have a good view rather then always a good look at PO, take the angle of the forward vector of CO. If it is quarter I of IV (position of a angle in math) you can assume, that ur currently just seeing the PO and not TO because the camera sits right beyond PO and looks to TO right through PO. If this happens set PO render to false. As soon as CO forward vector angle is quarter II-IV set PO render to true.

That's it. I will try to give u more in depth code tonight, because right now I'm at work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could check if the camera's position is between the player and the target and just rotate it 180º